# Phone connecting to lot of domains when not in use

Tags: xiaomi, dns, bloatware

I have noticed that my Redmi smartphone is connecting to a lot of sites when I am not even using it.
While going through the DNS logs in 1.1.1.1 vpn app, I have found these domains.

```
FindMYDevice??

find.api.micloud.xiaomi.net

in.find.api.micloud.xiaomi.net


SUS!

account.xiaomi.com

api.account.xiaomi.com

au.ff.avast.sec.miui.com

cryptauthenrollment.googleapis.com

digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com

e11.whatsapp.net

e6.whatsapp.net

footprints-pa.googleapis.com

g.whatsapp.net

geller-pa.googleapis.com

keybag.id.mi.com

notifications-pa.googleapis.com

playatoms-pa.googleapis.com

qcc.qualcomm.com

safebrowsing.googleapis.com

static.whatsapp.net

www.googleapis.com
```

I couldn't find any information on these online. Can anyone explain what these sites are used for and what will break if I block them permanently?

Comment: Use [Tracker Control](https://trackercontrol.org/) to figure out which app is calling which URL. You can then block some or all of them depending upon the classification groups Tracker Control uses. That way, you can also figure out if blocking them would break a critical functionality of the corresponding app or not. // I think Tracker Control looks for and shows only tracking URLs. Use NetGuard app's logging facility to log URL access attempts of each installed app.

Comment: @Firelord It seems network logging of both apps is less helpful than 1.1.1.1. I couldn't understand anything as it only showed IP addresses. I did enable all the permissions and options for the app to work properly.  It showed WhatsApp sticked with some entries but that's no progress at all as I could already guess it from the domains. No other applications appeared in the entries.